# Android how to add a header to this: new java.net.URL("http://example.com/").openStream()

Tags: java, android

I need to send a header If-Modified-Since to this address and only download if the server returns 200 not 304. Is there a way I can add/modify the header in this code?

```
new java.net.URL(API.JSON_ZIP_OF_ALL_FILES).openStream()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [`setRequestProperty()`](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/java/adding-header-for-httpurlconnection.html) method

Comment: The link doesn't point to anything helpful today.